# Encountering 'permission denied(publickey)' Error When Pushing to GitHub via SSH

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-bash, ssh-keys

git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
error: remote origin already exists.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

how to resolve this error

Tried some commands like:

ssh -T git@github.com
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 1920

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Permission+denied+publickey